# breezejs addEntityType issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm new to breezejs. I am trying to define my entity type in the client without getting metadata from the server. I have a property called ID in the server entity.

I've defaulted the naming convention in the client side to camel case using the following code.

```
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
```

so, I started to map the entity as follows

```
store.addEntityType({
        shortName: "Photo",
        namespace: "MyProj.Models",
        dataProperties: {
            id: {
                dataType: DataType.Guid,
                isNullable: false,
                isPartOfKey: true
            },
            title: {
                dataType: DataType.String
            },
            description: {
                dataType: DataType.String
            },
            createdDate: {
                dataType: DataType.DateTime
            },
        }
    });
```

This worked all fine, except the id field is not getting the proper value. instead, it has the default value set by the breeze datatype ctor which is equals to `Guid.Empty`.

by stepping through breezejs debug script, I found out that it looks for a property name called `Id` in the data that comes from the ajax request. But it can't find it as the property is `ID` so it initialize it to `empty guid` string. I assumed that by setting `nameOnServer` property of the `dataProperty` `id`, I will be able to fix it.

```
store.addEntityType({
        shortName: "Photo",
        namespace: "MyProj.Models",
        dataProperties: {
            id: {
                dataType: DataType.Guid,
                isNullable: false,
                nameOnServer: 'ID',
                isPartOfKey: true
            },
            title: {
                dataType: DataType.String
            },
            description: {
                dataType: DataType.String
            },
            createdDate: {
                dataType: DataType.DateTime
            },
        }
    });
```

But it didn't work.

Further digging through the breez.debug.js code, in the method `updateClientServerNames` on line 7154, it seems it ignores the `nameOnServer` that I have defined.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I commented out `breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();` line and changed the mapping details accordingly (i.e. change them to `PascalCase`. It works fine this way. but I want it to work on `camelCase` which is the javaScript standard. Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Feel like I spent my whole life through breeze documentation. Anyways, Finally solved the issue. To be honest, this wasn't a problem in breeze (but I wonder why it doesn't override the actual `nameOnServer` when I provide one). It's an error made by one of the developers in the early stage of the database implementation (probably 6 years ago). If the database adhered to Pascal Case naming convention, things would have worked perfectly fine.

As a solution I wrote a custom naming convention which corrects the naming convention error when it has `ID` in the name and combines it with `camelCase` naming convention.

```
var createInconsistenIDConvention = function () {
var serverPropertyNameToClient = function (serverPropertyName, prop) {

    if (prop && prop.isDataProperty && (prop.nameOnServer && prop.nameOnServer === "ID")) {
        return "id";
    } else {
        var firstSection = serverPropertyName.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase();
        var idSection = "";
        if (serverPropertyName.substr(1).indexOf("ID") != -1) {
            firstSection += serverPropertyName.substr(1, serverPropertyName.substr(1).indexOf("ID")).toLowerCase() + "Id";
        } else {
            firstSection += serverPropertyName.substr(1);
        }

        return firstSection;
    }
}
var clientPropertyNameToServer = function (clientPropertyName, prop) {
    if (prop && prop.isDataProperty && (prop.nameOnServer && prop.nameOnServer.indexOf("ID") != -1)) {
        return prop.nameOnServer;
    } else {
        return clientPropertyName.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + clientPropertyName.substr(1);
    }
}
return new breeze.NamingConvention({
    name: "inconsistenID",
    serverPropertyNameToClient: serverPropertyNameToClient,
    clientPropertyNameToServer: clientPropertyNameToServer
});
};
```

Not sure if the way I've used nameOnServer property is not correct. I couldn't find any documentation on that in breeze website.

please note that the above code only consider situations like ID, CountryID, GameID, PersonID etc.

Problem solved for now.

Comment: Amila,thanks for the comments.  We DO need to do a better job documenting the metadata. i.e. nameOnServer vs name and the associated rules.  Trying to get some of this documentation onto the website within the next few days, but we will still have a lot more to add. :)

Comment: Hi Jay. If one follows the tutorials, it helps somewhat to understand things and also, if when I get an error I debug it in the chrome console for hours. Doing so helped me to understand most of the stuff. Infact, I'm not using the above naming convention coz I figured out it'll be easy to change it in the edmx file in the long run. Now I'm trying to figure out how to assign lookups (list of countries) to a dropdown which is generated dynamically when the user clicks on edit. It's rather a knockout problem than a breezejs I think.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It was driving me crazy that it was ignoring the nameOnServer property. I just wanted everything, client & server, to be camelCase!